# i am making Login/Register System in nodejs and sql and facing a bug

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

when i enter email and password it and hit register it shows me following error

Cannot destructure property 'email' of 'req.body' as it is undefined.

I want it to be fetched through fetch api and post the data into data base

This is the html form

```
 <form  onsubmit = "return false;" id="form">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" autocomplete="off" required>
                  <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="error" style="display: none;" ></div>
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success" style="display: none;" ></div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Register</button>
              </form>
```

This is the event listener on submit

```
form.addEventListener("submit",() => {
    const register = {
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value
    }
    fetch("/api/register", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(register),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(
        data => {
            if(data.status =="error")
            {
                success.style.display = "none";
                error.style.display = "block";
                error.innerText = data.error;
            }
            else
            {
                success.style.display = "block";
                error.style.display = "none";
                error.innerText = data.success;
                
            }
        }
    )
})
```

This is "/api/register"

```
const db = require("../routes/db-config");

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


const register = async(req, res) =>{

    const email = req.body.email
    const Npassword = req.body.password

    if(!email || !Npassword) return res.json("Please Enter your email and password");
    else {
        console.log(email);
        db.query('SELECT email FROM data WHERE email = ?',[email], async (err, result)=>{
            if (err) throw err;
            if(result[0])return res.json({ status: "error", error: "This Email has already Taken"})
            else {
                const password = bcrypt.hash(Npassword, 8);
                console.log(password)
                db.query("insert into data SET ?" ,{email:email, password:password},(error, results)=>{
                    if(error) throw error;
                    return res.json({status: success, success: "User has been registered"})
                })
            }
        })
    } 
}

module.exports = register;
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that what is the API receives in the request body, cause the rest looks alright

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

I had to declare it earlier than the other statements